# lightning-input-field with time type not applying gmt offset when saving

Tags: lightning-recordeditform, timezone, lightning-inputfield, lightning-recordviewform

I have a lightning-record-edit-form which is rendering a lightning-input-field that happens to be of type Time.

The input renders correctly, however when I save the form, the offset from my timezone is not applied.

My timezone is GMT +1, so selecting a time such a 9AM should be stored as 8AM after subtracting the offset. However, when I save the form and query the database to see what was stored, I see 09:00:00.000Z.As you can see, the data was "saved as GMT" but the offset was not applied.

If that is not strange enough, I set up another form, this time a lightning-record-view-form with a lightning-output-field to render the same time field. The component displays 9am as the rendered value which means is not doing any kind of offset to the value that is stored in the database. If what is stored in the database is 09:00:00.000Z then i should see 10Am right? (GMT +1).

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: AFAIK Date time fields are being saved to db in GMT +0. Is it possible that every time you retrieve the field value, it is always converted to your timezone? Please try to change your user time zone, if the retrieved values get changed or not.

Comment: Changed my system and the user timezone and the same thing keeps happening. I'm not sure why!